# QGIS: Problems creating an HTML web map of my project

Tags: qgis

With my project settled, I have exported it to GeoPDF and would also like to create an HTML version.

Added qgis2web in the Plugins Manager, re-started QGIS.

When I choose Web/qgis2web/create a web map, the program gives me a spinning mouse for 2-3 minutes, then displays some Python errors, which are beyond my pay-grade.

QGIS 3.15
GDAL 3
Python 3.7
OSX High Sierra (10.13.6)
Mac mini mid 2011
2.3 ghz i5
16 GB RAM

The errors I receive look like this:

```
An alternative, ballpark-only transform was used when transforming coordinates between EPSG:26919 - NAD83 / UTM zone 19N and EPSG:3857 - WGS 84 / Pseudo-Mercator. The results may not match those obtained by using the preferred operation:
Possibly an incorrect choice of operation was made for transformations between these reference systems. Check the Project Properties and ensure that the selected transform operations are applicable over the whole extent of the current project.

2020-10-25T00:43:03     WARNING    Python error : An error has occurred while executing Python code: See message log (Python Error) for more details.
2020-10-25T00:43:03     WARNING    Used a ballpark transform from EPSG:26919 to EPSG:3857

Python Error
2020-10-25T00:43:03     WARNING    Traceback (most recent call last):
              File "/Users/house/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/qgis2web/utils.py", line 442, in exportRaster
              "OUTPUT": out_raster})
              File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/plugins/processing/tools/general.py", line 108, in run
              return Processing.runAlgorithm(algOrName, parameters, onFinish, feedback, context)
              File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/plugins/processing/core/Processing.py", line 153, in runAlgorithm
              raise QgsProcessingException(msg)
             _core.QgsProcessingException: Unable to execute algorithm
             Could not load source layer for INPUT: /var/folders/kn/4rm9tz_s6y39mr0rvfjjq3k80000gp/T/small_point_nw121603600920_piped_3857.tif not found
             
             During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
             
             Traceback (most recent call last):
              File "/Users/house/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/qgis2web/qgis2web.py", line 59, in run
              self.dlg = MainDialog(self.iface)
              File "/Users/house/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/qgis2web/maindialog.py", line 159, in __init__
              self.autoUpdatePreview()
              File "/Users/house/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/qgis2web/maindialog.py", line 334, in autoUpdatePreview
              self.previewMap()
              File "/Users/house/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/qgis2web/maindialog.py", line 337, in previewMap
              preview_file = self.createPreview()
              File "/Users/house/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/qgis2web/maindialog.py", line 300, in createPreview
              dest_folder=utils.tempFolder()).index_file
              File "/Users/house/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/qgis2web/olwriter.py", line 91, in write
              folder=dest_folder)
              File "/Users/house/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/qgis2web/olwriter.py", line 131, in writeOL
              popup, json, restrictToExtent, extent, feedback, matchCRS)
              File "/Users/house/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/qgis2web/utils.py", line 237, in exportLayers
              exportRaster(layer, count, layersFolder, feedback, iface, matchCRS)
              File "/Users/house/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/qgis2web/utils.py", line 444, in exportRaster
              shutil.copyfile(piped_3857, out_raster)
              File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/shutil.py", line 120, in copyfile
              with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc:
             FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/var/folders/kn/4rm9tz_s6y39mr0rvfjjq3k80000gp/T/small_point_nw121603600920_piped_3857.tif'
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error on QGIS 3.20.0 "Odense" (I posted the whole error message at the end of [this blog post](https://www.luisalucchese.com/post/how-to-leaflet-qgis2web-adjust-generated-map/)). My solution was to export the map on qgis2web plugin through QGIS 3.16 "Hannover" (LTS), this way, the algorithm ran without issues.